# Android: actionbar dissapeared after returning to the app

Tags: android, android-actionbar, onresume

I've got an app with `android:minSdkVersion` set to "4".

When I run this app on my HTC one X (4.0.3) I have a actionbar and everything is okay, but when I turn of my phone and return to the app the actionbar disappeared.

Is there an manifest command or something to always show the actionbar when possible?

This isn't allowed in my app because of the minSdkVersion.

```
    ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();
    actionBar.show();
```

Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [Android Compatibility Library](http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/support-library.html) for this; it will provide your app with an action bar on older versions of Android, and then you can use `getSupportActionBar()`.  It also provides you with an Activity base class you can extend; called `ActionBarActivity` which takes care of this sort of logic for you.

Alternately, you can check out [ActionBar Sherlock](http://actionbarsherlock.com/) which (to the best of my knowledge) provides a superset of the support library capability.

Answer (score 0):

Call `actionBar.show()` in your `Activity.onResume()` method. Every time your app gets paused, it will call your ActionBar.

Answer (score 0):

Just put this in your onCreate method of your activity :

```
            Actionbar actionbar;
    actionbar = getSupportActionBar();
```

THis should load the actionbar everytime the app is started

Comment: Thanks but this still results in: Call requires API level 11 (current min is 4): android.app.Activity#getActionBar